# RTL Error cannot find module @assets/logo-filled.png from src/component/index.tsx

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Getting below error

cannot find module `@assets/logo-filled.png from src/component/index.tsx`

if I replace `import logo from @assets/logo-filled.png` *with* `import logo from ../../../assets/logo-filled.png`

This line of import is working fine while running the application. But while running the test scripts `npm test` -> `react-scripts test`  the above error is popping up

test.test.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import {Logo} from "../components/logo";
describe('Describe...', () => {
    test('test ...', () => {
        console.log('the test');
        render(<Logo withoutText={true}/>);        
        expect(1).toBe(1)
    });
});
```

Logo.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Stack, Image, Text } from '@fluentui/react';
import { logoContainerStyles, textStyles } from './styles';

// ERROR thrown by below line
import logo from '@assets/icon-16.png';

// Works fine with below commented line
/** import logo from '../../../assets/icon-16.png'; */

export interface LogoProps {
  withoutText?: boolean;
}

export const Logo: React.FC<LogoProps> = props => {
  const { withoutText } = props;
  return (
    <Stack styles={logoContainerStyles} horizontalAlign="center">      
     <Image src={logo} alt="logo" width={64} shouldFadeIn={false} />      
     <Text styles={textStyles} variant="xLarge">         
       Hello StackOverflow
     </Text> 
    </Stack> 
  );
};
```

ts.config.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["../assets/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Any kind of help will much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We need a little bit more details on your setup. But it has to do with tsconfig.json and it's paths property. Also take a closer look at jest property in package.json, it is used to define aliases for tests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes your right it is something todo with ts config, I have updated the question.

Comment: How to setup paths and baseUrl in jest config

Answer (score 0):

In the `jest.config.js` use ,

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle other modules


    // Handle module aliases
    "^@/assets/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../assets/$1",
  },
```

If you want use module aliases with `TypeScript`

```
 "paths": {
      "@/assets/*": ["../assets/*"],
    }
```

Comment: I tried the above solution, but no luck!

Comment: I have edited my answer, Let's see if it works.